# Why do I need to reinstall the ARKit app after iOS update?

Tags: ios, iphone, unity-game-engine, arkit

I created an ARKit application (made in Unity) and installed it on my iphone. It works fine, but for some reason, sometimes, after the iOS update it stops working, and I have to reinstall it from the xCode again.

I use the same build version when reinstalling, nothing was changed in it, so why do I need to reinstall it after the iOS update every time?

Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: Whats the error message you got?

Comment: @JeanLuc No error message, I just can't launch the app. It closes immediately in one second after I click the app icon.

Comment: hm, usually that kind of behaviour happened when the provisioning profile or  iphone distribution certificate expired.